# awk search pattern in one file compare to another file and print columns of both file

Tags: awk

I'm trying to compare the second column of the file 1 and find this pattern in the second column of the file 2 to obtain an output with the id of the file 1 in column 1 and print the column 2 of the file 2 
I assume that in my file 1 and 2 there is more than one line with the same id 
Can awk do this ? Or another tool ? 
 Thanks for the help !

file 1

```
TRINITY_DN2107 cl14615
TRINITY_DN2107 cl10509
TRINITY_DN2107 cl01287
```

file 2

```
cl14615 pfam00932
cl14615 pfam08214
cl10509 pfam00651
cl01287 pfam13027
cl01287 pfam13340
```

file desired

```
TRINITY_DN2107 pfam00932
TRINITY_DN2107 pfam08214
TRINITY_DN2107 pfam00651
TRINITY_DN2107 pfam13027
TRINITY_DN2107 pfam13340
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
awk -v f=file_1 '
    BEGIN{while (getline < f) x[$2]=$1}
    {print x[$1], $2}' file_2
```

However, I note that your first file has the same values in first column.

Version without `BEGIN`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{h[$2]=$1; next}{print h[$1], $2}' file_1 file_2
```

Comment: Yes !  Many thanks 
As you said without BEGIN because I have the same values